# Will client timeout if a request on HTTP persistent connection takes a long time?

Tags: http, keep-alive

If we have a HTTP persistent connection, however one of the request takes a long time (say 30 seconds).
Assume client's timeout is 15 seconds.

1. Is client's reques-timeout respected when used over persistent connection ?
2. If yes, then does the connection break ?
3. Is there any way to avoid the entire connection from breaking, and instead just timing out on that one particular request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Client can specify timeout but it depends on the server configuration for using client timeout or its own timeout configuration. By default server side timeout configuration has more priority than client timeout configuration.
2. No
3. For having one particular request with different timeout config it's not possible on the same connection But, you can declare different http client config connection and use one of them for default and another one for request that need much more timeout value But they are not in the same keep-alive connection.
    Note, In the client side timeout configuration we have two different type of timeout 
   1- Open Connection Timeout 2- Read Response Timeout.
   The first one is declared for open connection between server and client and the second one is declared for how much time client needs to get response for his request.

Comment: what happens if client side timeout (10s) is smaller than server side timeout(15s) ?

Comment: In the event that either the client or the web server has a smaller Keep-alive value, that smaller value is the restricting factor.

Answer (score 0):

That depends of what client you are using and how the server is configured. The problem is more complicated... setting `keep-alive` in `http` won't avoid `tcp` timeouts at transport level, you need to set `tcp` timeout to `keep-alive` as well, but then server may not want to keep a connection for you as long as you would like to. For persistent connections it is better to use `udp` instead of `tcp` - it doesn't have such a strict flow control. Other thing is that `HTTP/2` has no such a thing as `keep-alive` at all, as things are handled in totally different way than in `HTTP/1`.  From the [HTTP/2 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.2):

> 8.1.2.2.  Connection-Specific Header Fields
>
> HTTP/2 does not use the Connection header field to indicate
> connection-specific header fields; in this protocol, connection-
> specific metadata is conveyed by other means.  An endpoint MUST NOT
> generate an HTTP/2 message containing connection-specific header
> fields; any message containing connection-specific header fields MUST
> be treated as malformed (Section 8.1.2.6).
>
> The only exception to this is the TE header field, which MAY be
> present in an HTTP/2 request; when it is, it MUST NOT contain any
> value other than "trailers".
>
> This means that an intermediary transforming an HTTP/1.x message to
> HTTP/2 will need to remove any header fields nominated by the
> Connection header field, along with the Connection header field
> itself.  Such intermediaries SHOULD also remove other connection-
> specific header fields, such as Keep-Alive, Proxy-Connection,
> Transfer-Encoding, and Upgrade, even if they are not nominated by the
> Connection header field.